# WordPress Cookie Security - Persistent Cookie comment_author change to session cookie

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, session-cookies, penetration-testing

Can someone explain to me how I would go about changing WordPress `comment_author` cookie expiery tag, I want to delete the `'Expires='` tag to change it to a session cookie.

Where would i do this in the php files?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to change expiration date, you can use [comment_cookie_lifetime](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_cookie_lifetime/) filter.

E.g. to expire it after two years:

```
add_filter('comment_cookie_lifetime', 2*YEAR_IN_SECONDS);
```

To change it to session, you need to remove default [wp_set_comment_cookies](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_comment_cookies/) from [set_comment_cookies](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/set_comment_cookies/) hook and add your own one to set session cookie.

Example:

```
remove_action('set_comment_cookies', 'wp_set_comment_cookies', 10, 2);

add_action('set_comment_cookies', function(\WP_Comment $comment, \WP_User $user)
{
    // set session
}, 10, 2);
```